# Скрыть дочернии элементы при клике

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно при клике скрыть все дочернии элементы класса tp-revslider-slidesli и показать все дочернии элементы класса tp-revslider-slidesli-2, делал так не получилось:

```js
$('.tparrows').click(function() {
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli').children('.tp-parallax-wrap').animate({
    width: ["toggle", "swing"], // ширина элемента
    height: ["toggle", "swing"], // высота элемента
    opacity: "toggle" // прозрачность элемента
  }, 1500, "linear"); // продолжительность и скорость анимации

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tp-revslider-mainul">
  <li class="tp-revslider-slidesli">
    <div class="parallax">Это скрыть</div>
    <div class="parallax">Это скрыть</div>
  </li>
  <li class="tp-revslider-slidesli-2">
    <div class="parallax">Это показать</div>
    <div class="parallax">Это показать</div>
  </li>

</ul>

<button class="tparrows">Click</button>
```

Comment: `class="tparrows"`

Comment: Не в этом дело, это тут опечатка, сори

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.tparrows').click(function() {
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli').find(".parallax").toggle(500);
  $('.tp-revslider-slidesli-2').find(".parallax").toggle(500);
});
```

```css
.tp-revslider-slidesli-2 .parallax {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="tp-revslider-mainul">
  <li class="tp-revslider-slidesli">
    <div class="parallax">AAA</div>
    <div class="parallax">BBB</div>
  </li>
  <li class="tp-revslider-slidesli-2">
    <div class="parallax">CCC</div>
    <div class="parallax">DDD</div>
  </li>

</ul>

<button class="tparrows">Click</button>
```

Comment: Немножко не так, tp-revslider-slidesli-2 - у меня по умолчанию скрыт, нужно что бы переключатель был, переключатель дочерних блоков. Как тут - https://demo.kallyas.net/sneakers-shop/

Comment: @ilyaaa521, Если "не так" - значит вопрос задан "не так". Код в ответе делает именно то, что ты спрашивал. Смотришь на этот код (желательно с пониманием написанного), и по аналогии пишешь свой.